# laravel jwt-auth Token is Invalid

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I built an api in Laravel using tymondesigns/jwt-auth to authenticate users.

I followed the tutorial on [github](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki) and the login is working correctly:

```
public function login() {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json(['error' => true], HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

        return response()->json(array(
            'user' => $user, 
            'token' => compact('token')['token'])
        );
    }
```

And for the response I got the token.

But every time I try to use the toke I got:

```
[
  "Token is invalid"
]
```

ie:

```
public function getUser() {
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        return response()->json(JWTAuth::toUser($token));
    }
```

This is a GET to `{{url}}/api/getUser` with the header `Authorization: Bearer {{token}}`

my routes.php contains the following:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
    Route::post('/login', 'API\UserController@login');
    Route::get('/getUser', ['before' => 'jwt-auth', 'uses' => 'API\UserController@getUser']);
});
```

How can I make this working with the token? Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:

I got a token like this:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3NtYXJ0YXBwXC9hcGlcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDY2Mjc5ODUxLCJleHAiOjE0NjYyODM0NTEsIm5iZiI6MTQ2NjI3OTg1MSwianRpIjoiYjNkZjViZGNiMjQ2YWU0NzVlZDYwODQxMWFlZDNkMTAifQ.pqU0pWKVzmOel51ObyE9vKLk07tefh2lDE-fp-AOavE
```

After I check the token on https://jwt.io, I got invalid signature.
Why I'm getting and invalid signature, and how can I make it valid?

Comment: What are the contents of the `routes.php` file?

Comment: I added the routes to my question, see edit

Comment: How exactly are you passing the token? Are you using Postman? The token should be passed without the braces `{{ }}`.

Comment: Yes I'm using Postman. An example of my header Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ......

Comment: In _Postman_, you are supposed to go to _Headers_ tab, then put `Authorization` in place of `key` and `Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ...` in place of `value`. I hope you are doing it this way.

Comment: Yes I'm doing this. Check this [printscreen](http://brunoramalho.pt/smartapp/postman.png). In this example I'm not using the environment vars.

Comment: Your _printscreen_ link isn't working

Comment: http://brunoramalho.pt/smartapp/postman.png

Comment: I think you should just delete the first row in _Headers_. May be just deselecting it isn't working. Because I can see `(2)` in the _Headers_ tab.

Comment: The first one is an environment var, and it's not selected. And when I delete that I got exactly the same message. When I don't select any I got the token is required.

Comment: Can you show the complete `token` that you are receiving? The `return response()->json(array(
            'user' => $user, 
            'token' => compact('token')['token'])
        );` in the `login()` function seems to be the culprit. It may not be returning a proper token.

Comment: Try returning the `token` like so `return response()->json(compact('token'));`

Comment: when I return response()->json(compact('token')); I got {
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3NtYXJ0YXBwXC9hcGlcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDY2MjYwOTQ2LCJleHAiOjE0NjYyNjQ1NDYsIm5iZiI6MTQ2NjI2MDk0NiwianRpIjoiMTEzOTJhMmQ1NDkwNWU2ZTNmYzM4NTYzYTY4ZWM5OGIifQ.naT6GXyyWdiApXimtdxrSJurAwBNI2AT1_hZls7TDmk"
}  And using this token I got the same error message

Comment: Are you using your original `getUser()` or the one I suggested in my answer?

Comment: that one you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function getUser() {
  // set the token on the object

  JWTAuth::parseToken();

  // get the user from token
  $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

  return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: the same problem. even if I take the 'before' => 'jwt-auth' from the route. I got the same error

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Try using the middleware as 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth' in your routes with @linuxartisan's answer

Comment: I'm using laravel 5, and My route has jwt.auth 'Route::get('/getUser', ['before' => 'jwt-auth', 'uses' => 'API\UserController@getUser']);'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Define a constructor, so that you can get the user by using $this->jwtauth->toUser() through out that class with out repeatedly using JWTAuth $jwtauth in the function.

```
private $jwtauth;

public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwtauth)
{
    $this->jwtauth = $jwtauth;
}

public function getUser()
{
    $user = $this->jwtauth->toUser();
    return response($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it just like that:

```
    public function login() {
         if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json(['error' => true], 
        HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
       }

    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

    return response()->json(array(
        'user' => $user, 
        'token' => compact(['token'])
    );
}
```